# Convert subarray index to array index in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

Imagine I have an array

```
A = [12 52 12 62 42];
```

With the "logical extraction indices" `C = logical([1 1 0 1 0])`, I form a subarray

```
B = A(C);
```

**The question**

What is an elegant way of finding element's index in `A`, given its index in `B` is, say, 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two options, either look for where the element of `B` matches an element of `A`, which could fail if `A` has repeats, or by using the `C` matrix, look for the n'th one.

```
A = [12 52 12 62 42];
C = logical([1 1 0 1 0])
B = A(C)

[~,idx]=find(A==B(3)) %// finds where the third element of B was in A
idx=find(cumsum(C)==3,1) %// finds where the third 1 in C is
```

Comment: plus 1, `cumsum` is damn smart.

Comment: Also, `A.*C` gives you a vector with elements of `A` where `C` is 1, and zeros where `C` is 0, which could be useful. You might be able to use that in your code as well, depending on what you are try to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

[`find`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) gives the answer. Let `indB` denote the index in `B`. Then the index in `A`, denoted `indA`, is

```
indA = find(C); %// find nonzeros in C
indA = indA(indB); %// take the indB-th nonzero in C
```