# Finding original index of subarrays in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, optimization

I have a question involving trying to use logical indexing to speed up some processing.  The solution might be somewhat related to this question:

[Convert subarray index to array index in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27414902/convert-subarray-index-to-array-index-in-matlab)

I'm trying to use logical indexing instead of using find, since it's often claimed to be slower.  The problem is like this:

I have four different find function where the resulting indices are whittled down.

```
cix1 = find(crossings_flow < max(flow(k+(0:1))));
cix2 = cix1(find(crossings_flow(cix1) > min(flow(k+(0:1)))));
cix3 = cix2(find(crossings_flow(cix2)-max([flow(ix(cix2)); flow(ix(cix2)+1)]) < 0));
cix4 = cix3(find(crossings_flow(cix3)-min([flow(ix(cix3)); flow(ix(cix3)+1)]) > 0));
```

The indices of `cix1` are fed into `cix2`.  And then so on for `cix3` and `cix4`.  The end result is that I need the indices of `cix4` which relate to the vector called crossings_flow.

It's easy enough to replace cix1 with a logical index:

```
crossings_flow < max(flow(k+(0:1)))
```

but then, when I want to get cix2, if i did

```
cix2 = cix1(crossings_flow(cix1) < max(flow(k+(0:1))) )
```

then i'm getting a logical array that's smaller in size, because it only relates to to a subarray of crossings_flow.

My question is, is there a way to logically index for this type of nested find problem, or is using find the fastest way to do this?  This is a section of code that is run many times, so I'm looking for anything that can help me speed things up.  So perhaps logical indexing might do that.  The question cited showed one method, but it did not involve nested finds like this problem.

Comment: Work with purely logical indices, no `find`s: then you'll keep the dimensions. `cix1=crossings_flow<max(flow(...)); cix2=crossings_flow(cix1)>min(flow(...))`, etc. Unless you really need to use indices related to the subarrays, but that shouldn't be too hard to avoid.

Comment: I don't think it works.  Say you have x= [ -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4].  then lets say the first condition is finding those greater than zero

test1= x>0.   

Of course we could just combine the conditions in this simple case, but in the other case, the conditions seem a bit more complicated

then if we want to find those greater than 2 of the ones we justsaw if we did as you suggest doing 
test2 = x(test1)>2

we end up with 
0     0     1     1
instead of  the full vector

Comment: Sorry, you're perfectly right. Use logical operations then: `test1= x>0; test2= x<2; x(test1 & test2)` returns elements for which both conditions are `true`.